# Why is the return being undefined? and how to solve?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to assign the snapshot value to a variable to be able to include in the list, so it keeps returning undefined.
childItem(childItem.name etc) values ​​are being added correctly, only profile.userName that returns as undefined
I'm using react native + firebase
I have tried several ways to solve I am not getting.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        list: []

    };
    firebase.database().ref('pets/lost').on('value', (snapshot) => {
        let state = this.state;
        state.list = [];

        snapshot.forEach((childItem) => {


            var profile =  firebase.database().ref('/users/' + childItem.val().userUid + '/profile').on('value', (snapshot) => {
                   return{
                       userName: snapshot.val().name
                   }

              });
            alert('nome ' + profile.userName);
            state.list.push({
                key: childItem.key,
                userName: profile.userName,
                name: childItem.val().name,
                breed: childItem.val().breed
            });

        });


        this.setState(state);

    });

}



render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <FlatList
                data={this.state.list}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    return (
                        <View style={styles.publiInfoContainer}>

                            <Image
                                style={styles.avatar}
                                source={{ uri: 'https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--HqfzgkTd--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/wp2qinp6fu0d8guhex9v.jpg' }}
                            />

                            <View style={styles.textPubliInfo}>
                                <Text style={styles.name}>{item.userName}</Text>
                                <Text style={styles.date}>14/10/1997</Text>
                            </View>


                        </View>

                    );
                }}

            />

        </View>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: when it says `on` that means an event. it is asynchronous. it may not return immediately on whatever the `profile` firebase object is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving the code where you are attempting to access and utilize `profile.username` inside of the inner on `value` callback to handle the async nature of the functionality.

```
          firebase.database().ref('/users/' + childItem.val().userUid + '/profile').on('value', (snapshot) => {
             const userName = snapshot.val().name;    
             alert(userName);
             state.list.push({
                key: childItem.key,
                userName,
                name: childItem.val().name,
                breed: childItem.val().breed
             });
                this.setState(state);
          });
```

Comment: Also, in your case, you should use the `once()` method instead of the `on()` one, which sets a listener.